Injured dog paw no vet available
I was playing with my dog as my parents were backing out and he jumped up and got in the way. I believe his paw got run over or got stuck and he suffered an injury on his paw between his toes. I immediately thought to take him to the vet, but all the nearest ones are closed and won’t open until Monday--two days from now.
He walks fine but licks his injury every once in a while. I tried to bandage it but he tried to remove it. What should I do? I’m not sure how to add pictures but to describe it: it’s a wound on his paw in between two of his toes and seems like it popped open, but I suppose no broken bones or anything since he’s walking like nothing happened.

It turns out the American Red Cross has a 35-minute video on pet first aid, at https://www.redcross.org/take-a-class/first-aid/cat-dog-first-aid

He needs to have a veterinarian's opinion. I suggest finding a reputable online vet or vet clinic.
Is it bleeding? Is there bruising? Is there a ball under the skin? Does he limp at all? Dogs will conceal injury quite well. If you have access to a muzzle, try to muzzle him. If not, put a sock over it (preferably a snug one) and use tape or a velcro strap to secure it.
